# MariaDB set timezone in config

Tags: timezone, mariadb

How do I set the server timezone in the MariaDB configuration?

The only thing I can find in the documentation is using command-line flags, which I don't want to do.

`default_time_zone`, which works on vanilla MySQL, isn't recognized by MariaDB.

Answer (score 15):

It is `default-time-zone` (`-` instead of `_`):

```
[server]
default-time-zone=+00:00
```

Comment: When I modify /etc/my.cnf.d/server.conf and run
`sudo systemctl start mariadb` I get the following message:
`Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`

Comment: I don't have a MariaDB server to test it, but the test suite uses this setting: https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.1/mysql-test/suite/storage_engine/my.cnf

Comment: Using names like "UTC" assumes you've run mysql_tzinfo_to_sql (see man page for details). If you haven't, try "default-time-zone=+00:00" instead.

Answer (score 7):

Pasi had the right idea. 'UTC' didn't work but '+00:00' did.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete summary collecting from above question and answers:

open

> /etc/my.cnf.d/server.conf

change to example:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]
default-time-zone=-06:00

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]
```

NOTE: for string

> default-time-zone=-06:00 // this is equivalent to (america/edmonton)

You will need to figure out for your timezone to do so look up here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Restart the mysql server:

> service mariadb restart

Testing:

```
[smith@home my.cnf.d]# mysql -u smith -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 17
Server version: 10.2.31-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2020-04-22 11:19:38 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: i ran this command `default-time-zone=+05:30` and it gives me  `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'default-time-zone=+05:30` error. Any idea?

Comment: Server version: 10.6.9-MariaDB Source distribution